# unable to exclude node_modules from the folder_project

Tags: rsync

I have 2 folders named as `rsync` & `folder_project` one at path **D://rsync** and other at path **D://project/project1/folder_project**.

folder_project contains the `.ignore` file which contains the path for `node_modules` present in folder_project.

I am syncing my local files to remote machine, so I have created the rsync command in the rsync folder with a config file.The files in rsync are as follows:
rsync --> `config.js` `node_modules` `ltor.ts`

**config.js**

```
module.exports = { 

Inputs:  {
            source : '../project/project1/folder_project',
            destination:'ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/ec2-user/',
            ignore: '../project/project1/folder_project/.ignore'        
         }
}
```

**ltor.ts**

```
//all imports are done.


function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(stdout) }

var onChangeFn = function (watch_directory, destination_directory, ignoreFile) {

    var command = 'rsync -avzH -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress --delete --exclude-from=' + ignoreFile + ' ' + watch_directory + ' ' + destination_directory;

    exec(command, puts);
}
```

**Question**: My rsync command is ignoring node_modules from the present or current directory, I want to exclude the node modules from the folder_project directory.
How can I achieve this?